# Como leer archivos de .msg con Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo como 100 archivos .msg. Estos archivos contienen texto sin tabular alineados solo usando espacios. Mi objetivo es hacer un DF con estos datos usando Pandas donde cada fila sea el Rain gauge. Los encabezados de las columnas serian el dia y el tiempo y su valor seria "Pasthour"

Este es el error que me da al ejecutar el codigo y asi continua con todos los archivos.

```
Error processing file FW_ Rain Report at 7_2_2020 10_39_40 PM.msg: list index out of range
Error processing file FW_ Rain Report at 7_2_2020 11_39_40 PM.msg: list index out of range
```

Este es el codigo que uso

```
import os
import extract_msg
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Directory containing .msg files
directory = 'C:\\Users'

# Initialize an empty dictionary to store the data
data = {}

# Loop through each file in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.msg'):
        try:
            # Extract the content of the .msg file
            msg = extract_msg.Message(os.path.join(directory, filename))
            content = msg.body
            
            # Extract the timestamp
            timestamp_line = content.split('\n')[3]
            timestamp_str = timestamp_line.split('at ')[1].strip()
            timestamp = datetime.strptime(timestamp_str, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
            
            # Extract the Rain Gauge data
            lines = content.split('\n')
            for line in lines:
                if line and line.split()[0] != 'Gauge':
                    parts = line.split()
                    gauge = parts[0]
                    past_hour = parts[1]
                    
                    # Add the data to the dictionary
                    if gauge not in data:
                        data[gauge] = {}
                    data[gauge][timestamp] = past_hour
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing file {filename}: {e}")

# Convert the dictionary to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T

# Sort the columns (timestamps)
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv('rain_gauge_data.csv')

print("Data has been saved to 'rain_gauge_data.csv'")
```

Asi es el formato de los archivos msg de outlook.

```
________________________________________
From: Random <user@gmail.com>
Sent: Sunday, July 2, 2020 9:39:41 PM (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
To: Gauge-Rain Notification
Subject: Rain Report at 7/2/2020 9:39:40 PM

Rain Report at 7/2/2020 9:39:40 PM

Rain    Past    This
Gauge   Hour    Event**

Pereira    0.00          0.00
Puebla    0.30          0.49
CI       0.00          0.11
Tokito     0.01          0.18
CO       0.00          0.04
KP          N/A          N/A
DSS      0.00           0.00
PL       0.00          0.00
TSM      0.00          0.00
PKP      0.00          0.01
RP      1.00          1.42
HP      0.00          0.00
GG      0.20          0.45
BB      0.00          0.28

Since the onset of this particular rain event. (May include rainfall before midnight) **Each rain gauge has separate rain events.

Flow Report at 7/2/2020 9:39:40 PM
```

Esto es mas lo que busco usando los valores del "pasthour"

```
Past Hour
Gauge   07/02/2020 22:39:40 07/02/2020 23:39:40 07/02/2020 03:08:12 07/02/2020 04:08:12
Pereira         .90              .20                0
Puebla          .50               0                 0
CI              .63               .50               0
Tokito          0                 0                 0
CO             0                  0                 .05
KP             N/A                N/A               N/A
DSS             0                 0                 0
PL              0                 0                 0
TSM             0                 0                 0
PKP             0                 0                 0
RP              0                 0                 0
HP              0                 0                 0
GG              0                 0                 0
BB              0                 0                 0
```

Comment: `content.split('\n')[3]` no hace lo que pensás, elige la linea `To: Gauge-Rain Notification`. ¿No sería `content.split('\n')[4]`?